# Rename local path of team foundation server project (TFS 2010)

Tags: tfs, path, local

I have made a "get latest version" on a team foundation server project. I think (not sure) this has
produced a local workspace on my computer where it has put all the files. Now
I want to rename the local path. Can I just do this in windows explorer or will it
cause any problems in TFS?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: What do you want to happen after the rename?  Do you want to be able to do a get latest to the new path?  Or do you want to have TFS no longer contain a workspace mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using TFS 2010 then it will not cause any problems for TFS. TFS will not see the files that were previously pulled down to your work space since you moved them. It would be as if you deleted the files locally.

However, if you are using TFS 2012 then you might run into unattended consequences based on the new local work space feature since it lets you make edits while being offline and disconnected from TFS. Still though if you are renaming the folder you should be fine.

[TFS 2012 - local work spaces](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/11/02/local-workspaces-in-tfs-2012.aspx)

Comment: thanks, really helpful, but I thought it was possible to just rename the local folder in windows explorer. This is not possible because it is write-protected.

Comment: Just right-click and remove read-only attribute. As long as you do not check anything in then TFS will not get updated. If you keep the folder in your same work space then TFS will see it as a new folder. However, you can either move it to a folder that is not in your work space or again just never add-check in to tfs.

Comment: When I referenced your work space for clarity if you have $/ProjectA mapped to your local path C:\ProjectA and you rename it to C:\ProjectB in TFS 2010 it treats it as not being in your workspace. If you have something like C:\Source mapped to $/ProjectA and rename the folder C:\Source\ProjectA to C:\Source\ProjectB then TFS 2010 will see it and allow you to add it to source control. Hope this helps. You are fine renaming your folder.